# Bouncing button on Raspberry Pi with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I'm a newbie to qt and I'm trying to use Raspberry Pi with jessie.

I have an interesting problem.
The buttons that I have added to the form are bouncing (like I'm pushing an not, pushing and not) but the buttons on anyother existing software on jessie not, as seen on the video.
I think the problem is not caused by hardware, its by software that I dont know.

I'm sorry I couldnt find a way to share video directly, so here is the link from tinypic.com ;

[Video Link](http://tinypic.com/r/52euq9/9)

I'm using raspbian jessie on Raspberry pi2 with Qt 5.3.2 ( GCC 4.9.2 , 32 bit).

Can you help me? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: If the problem is the software would be nice to show your code.

Comment: I didnt write any code to project. Just created the project and added buttons on the form. And the result is like on the video.

Comment: It looks like Qt is rendering the view over and over. If you catch the events then you can test whether they are registering more button clicks.

Comment: I cant catch for 1 button click because I need an event for while pressing...